# In Lua, why might a function or expression evaluate multiple times in an update call?

Tags: lua, function-call

Working in Lua and I currently I have a function that does:

```
function Entity:damage(dmg)

    self.health = self.health - dmg 
end
```

when I call it in another class's update function, like so:

```
function Room:update(dt)

    if not entity.dead and self.player:collides(entity) then
        self.player:damage(1)
end
```

instead of only dealing 1 damage, it actually deals up to 13 damage, as if the function is being called multiple times, but I'm not sure why that would be? I have very similar functions that are all doing the same thing and I'm not sure why the function/expression therein is being evaluated multiple times?

I've omitted a lot of code because I'm not sure what is relevant to helping. (I am using a Class library and player inherits from entity)

understandably a lot of code is missing and I'll likely end up debugging this myself, but if anyone has a suggestion that might be helpful/steer me in some direction I'd appreciate it, and I do apologize for the poorly formed question.

Comment: "*I'm not sure why that would be?*" We're not sure why that would be either, because we don't have *any of the code* around this. We have no idea what any of these functions or classes mean or the particulars of how they work. You're just going to have to put in the debugging effort. Look at the call stack in `damage` and see how it got called. And so forth.

Comment: ok sure, I actually would prefer debugging it myself sometimes, as I'm not quite how to phrase questions on here and avoid ire--I think I found a useful discussion of how to use Lua's debugging tools too!

Comment: instead of "a class library" you could simply name and ideally link it. if you only tag your qeustion "Lua" you should assume that anything outside the Lua reference manual is unknown to us and hence you have to provide code or we know as much as you do

Comment: if `self.player:damage(1)` is being called 13 times I would first check if it is only called in `Room:update(dt)`. If so should `self.player:collides(entity)` be true more than once?  update functions like that are often called each frame, so a wild guess would be that, depending on your physics, your collision state could be longer than 1 frame. Imagine I would punch your face. While my fist is in contact with your face for 300ms or so, damage is only inflicted once.

Comment: Is there any kind of multithreading involved? If so, some functions are may be not thread-safe (further reading: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial). Also, like in a some other recent question about Lua, you could be injuring upvalues, instead of `self`, other parametres or local values.

Comment: these comments are super helpful and give me a lot to think about in terms of debugging, thank you ! I will post back again with a solution if I stumble upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who commented; with your help, I found out what was going on!

First, Piglet you were correct--the 'collision' check state was longer than 1 frame. However, once I fixed that, I still noticed I was getting the wrong return value for

```
function Room:update(dt)

    if not entity.dead and self.player:collides(entity) then
        self.player:damage(1)
end
```

and I think Alexander you were correct in pointing out the multithreading or upvalues--that is a little bit beyond my comprehension at the moment-- but I checked the page linked and discovered that when I moved the function call 'upstream', I was getting the return value I expected.

So it seems perhaps where I was calling the function resulted in it being called or processed multiple times by the update functions of various classes.

Thanks for the comments; I'll use them to improve my question asking and also my general knowledge :)